# Given terms of two sequences converging to same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say we have two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ defined as usual for all $n \in N$.

Say $\lim{a_n}=L$ and $\lim{b_n}=L$ denote the infinite limits of these sequences.

By definition of $\lim{x_n}$, we see that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we can pick some $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$  such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>N$, $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$.

So, we can pick for each of these sequences respectively some $N_a$ and some $N_b$ where $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ and $|b_n - L| < \epsilon$.

**Question**

> Is it true that $N_a > N_b$ implies $a_n = b_n$ for all $n \ge N_a$ and similarly, $N_a < N_b$ implies $a_n = b_n$ for all $n \ge N_b$.

In other words, are the terms of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ identical for any $n$ greater than the maximum of their respective $N$ values?

---

**Idea**

I believe this because for all $\epsilon > 0$  and for all $n \ge N$ we have $0 \le |x_n - L| < \epsilon$ which is equivalently $0 < |x_n - L| < \epsilon \lor 0 = |x_n - L| < \epsilon$. But since $0 < \epsilon$ is arbitrary, there is no $0 < |x_n - L| < \epsilon$ so we must conclude $0 = |x_n - L| < \epsilon$. Thus, $0 = |x_n - L|$ gives $x_n = L$ for all $n \ge N$.

I'd like to end here for concision.

**Brief Example**

A brief motivating example I could expand on. Say $(a_n)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ and $(b_n)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}\right)$.

Then we see $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$ for $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$.

This would be since  $N_a = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ and $N_b = \frac{1}{\epsilon^3}$ and since $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}>\frac{1}{\epsilon^3}$.

Note: The assumption is that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we know $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}} < \epsilon$ or that both sequences converge to zero.

**Motivation**: In good faith, this is a lemma. I am trying to prove the squeeze theorem.

Comment: $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n =-1/n$ both converge to $L=0$, but $a_n \ne b_n$ for *all* $n$.

Comment: You also can take the example $a_n=(-1)^n/n$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}/2n$ for an alternating example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to prove the squeeze theorem, note that if $a_n \le c_n \le b_n$ then one has for $n > \max\{N_a, N_b\}$:
$$c_n - L = c_n - a_n + a_n - L \ge a_n - L > - \epsilon$$
and similarly, by involving $b_n$, you get $c_n - L < \epsilon$. In conclusion, $|c_n-L| <\epsilon$.
However, what you are claiming does not hold as pointed out in the comments and even if you assume many more things.

The reason your argument doesn't work is: the $\epsilon$ is not arbitrary in the sense that $0 \le |x_n - L| <\epsilon$ holds for all $n$ and all $\epsilon$. What is specifically true is that given $\epsilon$, you can find an $N$ **which is a function of $\epsilon$** such that for $n > N$ etc. In this sense, the whole thing is dependent on the $\epsilon$ you choose. Hence, a choice must be made and that's when you get all that.

Sequences generally never satisfy your claims. A sequence converging to $L$ will become arbitrarily close to $L$ but will not become $L$ itself. Same goes for the other claim about sequences converging to the same limit.